# XML to CSV with variable number of grouped elements

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am having trouble trying to work out how to convert the following xml file to csv.
It has 2 key elements (vdisk) with a variable number of grouped elements.
Here is my attempt.  Any help is appreciated :-)

file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<raid>
<system>
<name>ARRAY1</name>
<status>ok</status>
<network>
<ip1>192.168.15.9</ip1>
<ip2>192.168.15.10</ip2>
<gateway1>192.168.15.254</gateway1>
<netmask2>255.255.255.0</netmask2>
</network>
<name>a6180-1</name>
<vdisk>
<vdisk_idx>SITE-A</vdisk_idx>
<volume_name>data1</volume_name>
<volume_id>5DF4</volume_id>
<volume_size>21474836480</volume_size>
<volume_name>home1</volume_name>
<volume_id>F0DD</volume_id>
<volume_size>32212254720</volume_size>
<volume_name>data2</volume_name>
<volume_id>F251</volume_id>
<volume_size>161061273600</volume_size>
<volume_name>archive</volume_name>
<volume_id>F252</volume_id>
<volume_size>161061273600</volume_size>
</vdisk>
<vdisk>
<vdisk_idx>SITE-B</vdisk_idx>
<volume_name>data</volume_name>
<volume_id>A33B</volume_id>
<volume_size>150323855360</volume_size>
<volume_name>home</volume_name>
<volume_id>9E80</volume_id>
<volume_size>64424509440</volume_size>
<volume_name>Archive</volume_name>
<volume_id>6D30</volume_id>
<volume_size>42951770112</volume_size>
</vdisk>
<other>
<cruft>
</cruft>
</other>
</system>
</raid>
```

file.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />
  <!-- define an array containing the fields we are interested in -->
  <xsl:variable name="fieldArray">
    <field>volume_name</field>
    <field>vdisk_idx</field>
    <field>volume_size</field>
    <field>volume_id</field>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:param name="fields" select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='fieldArray']/*" />
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- output the header row -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- output newline -->
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="raid/system/vdisk"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="vdisk/vdisk_idx">
    <xsl:variable name="currIDX" select="." />
  </xsl:template>    
  <xsl:template match="vdisk">
    <xsl:variable name="currNode" select="." />
    <!-- output the data row -->
    <!-- loop over the field names and find the value of each one in the xml -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
      <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$currNode/*[name() = current()]" />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- output newline -->
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using command line xslt processor (xsltproc)

xsltproc file.xsl file.xml

```
volume_name,vdisk_idx,volume_size,volume_id
data1,SITE-A,21474836480,5DF4
data,SITE-B,150323855360,A33B
```

but I would like/expect:

```
volume_name,vdisk_idx,volume_size,volume_id
data1,SITE-A,20.000 GB,5DF4
home1,SITE-A,30.000 GB,F0DD
data2,SITE-A,150.000 GB,F252
archive,SITE-A,150.000 GB,F251
data,SITE-B,140.000 GB,A33B
home,SITE-B,60.000 GB,9E80
Archive,SITE-B,40.002 GB,6D30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/raid">
    <xsl:text>volume_name,vdisk_idx,volume_size,volume_id&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="system/vdisk/volume_name">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../vdisk_idx"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(following-sibling::volume_size[1] div 1000000000, '0.000 GB')"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::volume_id[1]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```